# Getting to know Ember StateManager, am I coding this right?

Tags: ember.js

I am getting my feet wet with Ember.JS StateManager, and I am currently following the online documentation at: http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.StateManager.html

I have done my best with this fiddle but cannot seem to get anything visual out at all. I have done numerous searches here at SOF and Google.

I have three states with three list item which trigger these states in view. I have placed a "ready function" within "Application.create({}" which fires, but as soon as the StateManager is initialized, "ready function" doesn't fire. I would highly appreciate your input and help.

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/exciter/NRmHc/12/

APP CODE
    $(function(){

```
    App = Ember.Application.create({

        ready: function(){
            //alert("APP INIT");
        }
    });

    App.stateManager = Ember.StateManager.create({

        showFirstState: function(manager){
            App.stateManager.transitionTo('startupState');
        },

        showSecondState: function(manager){
            App.stateManager.transitionTo('second');
        },

        showThirdState: function(manager){
            App.stateManager.transitionTo('third');
        },

        showFourthState: function(manager){
            App.stateManager.transitionTo('fourth');
        },

       // INIT STATE
        initialState: 'startupState',
        startupState: Ember.State.create({
            templateName: 'startup',
            classNames: ['state','black'],
            enter: function() { alert("STARTUP ENTERED"); }
        }),

        second: Ember.State.create({
            templateName: 'second',
            classNames: ['state','orange'],
            enter: function() { alert("SECOND ENTERED"); }          
        }),

        third: Ember.State.create({
            templateName: 'third',
            classNames: ['state','lime'],
            enter: function() { alert("THIRD ENTERED"); }
        }),

        fourth: Ember.State.create({
            templateName: 'fourth',
            classNames: ['state','blue'],
            enter: function() { alert("FOURTH ENTERED"); }
        }),

    });
    App.initialize();
});
```

HTML:

```
    <!--    CHECK TO SEE IF CSS IS FUNCTIONAL   
    <div id="state" class="state blue">
        STATE
    </div>
    -->
    <script type="text/x-handlebars">
        <nav>
         <ul>
            <li {{action "showFirstState" target="App.stateManager"}}>First State</li>
            <li {{action "showSecondState" target="App.stateManager"}}>Second State</li>
            <li {{action "showThirdState" target="App.stateManager"}}>Third State</li> 
            <li {{action "showFourthState" target="App.stateManager"}}>Fourth State</li>
        </ul>
        </nav>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="startup">
       <h2> STARTUP STATE </h2>
    </script>


    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="second">
       <h2>SECOND STATE</h2>
    </script>


    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="third">
       <h2>THIRD STATE</h2>
    </script>

    <script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="fourth">
       <h2>THIRD STATE</h2>
    </script>
```

CSS:

```
nav { background-color:#e9e9e9; padding: 1em 0 1em 0; }
nav li { display: inline; cursor: pointer; padding:0 1em 0 1em;}
.state { width:700px; height:500px; margin:0 auto; padding:0; background-color:#c9c9c9; }
.black { background-color:#666; }
.blue { background-color:#6699cc; }
.orange { background-color:#FF6600; }
.lime { background-color:#CCFF33; }
```

Comment: Your spelling of `tranisitionTo` is wrong. Should be `transitionTo`

Comment: Thanks Luke, aside from the misspelled "transitionTo", there were other major issues with the code which now have fixed. Now I am able to get the "stateManager.transitionTo() function" to fire for each state from main nav. I have also included "enter: function" for each state so when a state is called, I am able to see the enter function firing, however, I am unable to visually see the states changing, in other words, css is not being applied since I have different colors for each state. JSFiddle has been updated as well. Thank you.

Comment: States are not directly view related. They are conceptual. You need to do things in the states (like connect outlets or set controller properties that views are bound to) in order to make anything happen with the view layer on state change.

Comment: Thank you Luke. I am developing a simple widget which strictly answer driven. User answers a question by selecting "yes" or "no" and depending upon that answer user is taken to the next screen. I was thinking about using "STATES", but I think I should just have "VIEWS" and then "STATES" in those views if needed. What is your take on it, plz? Thx

Comment: it depends on what "the next screen" is. States are good for modeling different states of a user interface. If there are two different modes of the site (e.g. asking and answering), then the StateManager approach might be useful. Doing a napkin sketch of the states of your app is usually a good place to start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the feeling that what you want is not a statemanager but a router. Have a look at this [link](http://www.kaspertidemann.com/canonical-emberjs-routing-example/) for further info.

Comment: Thanks Rudi, this is exactly what I had in mind. Thanks a lot.